# Quantified formula values and "replacement notation"

Tags: logic

Inside my notes I have the following:

[image]

[image]

I do not see why the notation v(u/d) is necessary; why can we not simply say, for the ∀ case, that $∀xA(x)^v = 1$ if $A(d)^v = 1$ for every d ∈ D? What makes the whole notion of replacing u's with individuals d's necessary, when u's are arbitrary variables anyways and we could just specify the "for all individuals" to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purposes of meta-logic you really want to be clear on the distinction between the language we use to describe some possible domain, and any domain itself.

Here, the $d$ is a mathematical symbol we use to point to an object from some domain. The $u$ is a symbol of our logic language... it only denotes $d$ if we define a valuation that says so ... though other valuations could have $u$ to point to other objects in the domain.

An expression like $A(d)$ is really inappropriate: it mixes a mathematical symbol into a string of symbol from our language of logic.

One way in which this distinction can become pretty important is that we typically assume that our language uses finite strings of symbols, meaning that there is a countable number of variables and constants. However, a domain could be uncountable, such as the real numbers.